# Live Wallpaper - Canvas Flicker

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am trzing to make a simple Live wallpaper. It is supposed to draw circles of random color, diameter and position. And when the scren is touched it should do random circle on the touch position.
Currently ll works, the only problem is that the circles appear and disappear. I guess I should draw on a bitmap?
Here is my source. Does anybody have any idea, how to make this to work so it simply adds the circles over each other without them disappearing and appearing again?

```
package com.my.livewallpaper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyWallpaperEngine();
    }

    private class MyWallpaperEngine extends Engine {
        private final Handler handler = new Handler();
        private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                draw();
            }

        };
        private List<MyPoint> circles;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private int width;
        int height;
        public Canvas canvas = null;
        private boolean visible = true;
        private int maxNumber;
        private int timestamp=0;
        private boolean touchEnabled;
        public MyWallpaperEngine() {
            circles = new ArrayList<MyPoint>();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            handler.post(drawRunner);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            this.visible = visible;
            if (visible) {
                handler.post(drawRunner);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            this.visible = false;
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            //Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) {
                    drawCircles(canvas, x, y);
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null)
                {holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);}
            }
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        private void draw() {
            SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            //Log.e("Msg","What you have to print");
            try {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) {
                    drawCircles(canvas,-1f,-1f);
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) 
                {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
            if (visible) {
                handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 400);
            }
        }

        // Surface view requires that all elements are drawn completely
        private void drawCircles(Canvas canvas, float xx, float yy) {
            float minX = 10.0f;
            float maxX = 60.0f;
            Random rand = new Random();
            float diameter = rand.nextFloat() * (maxX - minX) + minX;
            float x = xx;
            float y = yy;

            if (xx==-1) {
                x = (float) (width * Math.random());
                y = (float) (height * Math.random());
            }
            paint.setARGB(rand.nextInt(200), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, diameter, paint);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code it will help you.

```
package com.fingerprintmagic;

public class LineDrawPoint {
    Float x = 0.0f;
    Float y = 0.0f;
    String text;

    public LineDrawPoint(String text, Float x, Float y) {
        super();
        this.text = text;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

And this is servicce

```
package com.fingerprintmagic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class FingerPrintService extends WallpaperService {

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Canvas c = null;
    private List<LineDrawPoint> point;
    Paint paint;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        point = new ArrayList<LineDrawPoint>();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new FingerPrintEngine();
    }

    class FingerPrintEngine extends Engine {

        private Boolean visble = true;
        private final Handler handle = new Handler();
        public Bitmap backgroundImage;

        public FingerPrintEngine() {
            backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.cupid_02);

        }

        private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                draw(point);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public Bundle onCommand(String action, int x, int y, int z,
                Bundle extras, boolean resultRequested) {
            return super.onCommand(action, x, y, z, extras, resultRequested);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset,
                int yPixelOffset) {
            draw(point);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
            this.visble = false;
            handle.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            point.add(new LineDrawPoint(String.valueOf(point.size() + 1), x, y));
            draw(point);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            this.visble = visible;
            if (visible) {
                handle.post(drawRunner);
            } else {
                handle.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
            }
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
        }

        private void draw(List<LineDrawPoint> point) {
            holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null) {
                    c.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
                    drawCircles(c, point);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                try {
                    if (c != null) {
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                    handle.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                    if (visble) {
                        handle.postDelayed(drawRunner, 1);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void drawCircles(Canvas canvas, List<LineDrawPoint> circles) {
        for (LineDrawPoint point : circles) {
            canvas.drawPoint(point.x, point.y, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

You can change drawCircle method for your requirement